# Is it possible for an address to be both controlled by a smart contract and a key?

Tags: go-ethereum, openethereum

The address a contract lives at is calculated based on constructor arguments (plus some other stuff) and keys can be generated randomly. Has there ever been a collusion? How does the protocol handle value stored at address controlled by both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question not that long ago and the answer is in [EIP-3607](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3607).

> Ethereum addresses are currently only 160 bits long. This means it is
> possible to create a collision between a contract account and an
> Externally Owned Account (EOA) using an estimated 2**80 computing
> operations, which is feasible now given a large budget (ca. 10 billion
> USD). The fix in this EIP prevents the worst possible attack, where a
> safe looking contract (e.g. a token wrapper or an AMM-type contract)
> is deployed to attract user funds, which can then be spent using the
> EOA key for the same address.

I am not aware of any precedent on that matter, but maybe someone else may know of one. So yes, it's theoretically possible.. but EIP-3607 evicts tx from accounts that do have deployed code, so, technically, no EOA is allowed to act on behalf of a CA even if that EOA have all the keys to prove its identity, CA has precedence.

This EIP is already implemented, the check can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_transition.go#L229) in go-ethereum.